# Problema com minha barra horizontal

Tags: c, c++

Estou tendo problemas com a minha barra horizontal, o problema é que ela não está aumentando o valor da variável "iVar" de 1 em 1, está aumentando de 5 em 5 ou até mais dependente de quanto eu passo no valor iMax, como eu arrumo esse problema?

```
#define SLIDER_WIDTH        250
#define SLIDER_HEIGHT       8
#define MAX_SLIDERS     30

int SliderPos[MAX_SLIDERS] = { 0 };

int iNumSliders = 0;

void AddSliderBar(int iPosX, int iPosY, int iMinVal, int iMaxVal, std::string sText, int &iVar)
{
    Color SliderColor1 = Color(200, 000, 000);
    Color SliderColor2 = Color(200, 000, 000);

    SliderPos[qntSliders] = iPosX + (iVar - iMinVal) * SLIDER_WIDTH / (iMaxVal - iMinVal);

    if (bMouseInRegion(iPosX, iPosY + 11, SLIDER_WIDTH, SLIDER_HEIGHT) && bMouseClicked())
        iVar = (Cur.x - iPosX) * (iMaxVal - iMinVal) / SLIDER_WIDTH;

    (iVar > iMaxVal) ? iVar = iMaxVal : iVar = iVar;
    (iVar < iMinVal) ? iVar = iMinVal : iVar = iVar;

    PrintText(x, y - 3, SliderColor1, FL_RIGHT, "%s: %i", sText.c_str(), iVar);

    // Slider cursor
    Draw.FillRGB(SliderPos[qntSliders], iPosY + 8, 2, SLIDER_HEIGHT, SliderColor1);

    // Slider bar
    Draw.FillRGB(iPosX, iPosY + 11, SLIDER_WIDTH, 2, SliderColor2);

    iNumSliders++;
}
```

Comment: Se o aumento vem daqui `iVar = (Cur.x - iPosX) * (iMaxVal - iMinVal) / SLIDER_WIDTH;` porque seria de `1` em `1` ?

Comment: Não sei, penso que tenha um jeito melhor de calcular isso para que o aumento fique de 1 em 1, a questão é que eu quebrei a cabeça e não conseguir fazer esse calculo funcionar.

Comment: O que é isso? Programação GUI?

Comment: Sim, para uma aplicação DirectX 9.